# Regex Pattern: Unclosed group

Tags: java, regex

I need to match the following date patterns:

```
dd-mmm-yyyy (TBC)
dd-mmm-yyyy (TBD)
dd-mmm-yyyy
```

but I get the following exception and I don't understand what the error is.
I am pretty sure of the date part, what I suspect as source of error is the TBC/TBD part that must be optional.

```
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 614
^(29-02-(2000|2400|2800|(19|2[0-9](0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))))[ \(TB(C|D)\)]$|^((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])-((FEB)|(feb)|(Feb)|(FEV)|(fev)|(Fev))-((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}))[ \(TB(C|D)\)]$|^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(((JAN)|(jan)|(Jan))((MAR)|(mar)|(Mar))((MAY)|(may)|(May)|(MAI)|(mai)|(Mai))((JUL)|(jul)|(Jul)|(JUI)|(jui)|(Jui))((AUG)|(aug)|(Aug)|(AUO)|(auo)|(Auo))((OCT)|(oct)|(Oct))((DEC)|(dec)|(Dec)))-((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}))[ \(TB(C|D)\)]$|^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)-(((APR)|(apr)|(Apr)|(AVR)|(avr)|(Avr))((JUN)|(jun)|(Jun)|(JUI)|(jui)|(Jui))((SEP)|(sep)|(Sep)((NOV)|(nov)|(Nov))-((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}))[ \(TB(C|D)\)]$
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
```

Do you have any hint?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use regex101 for that - https://regex101.com/r/mMcErb/1. It shows you the unpaired parenthesis at once. BTW, `[ \(TB(C|D)\)]` is a typo - why did you put it into a character class? I think you wanted to write `(?: \(TB[CD]\))?`

Comment: Try `(?i)^29-02-(?:2[048]00|(?:19|2[0-9](?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])-fe[vb]-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(jan|ma[ryi]|ju[li]|au[go]|oct|dec)-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)-(?:a[pv]r|ju[ni]|sep|nov)-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/LShzz4/2

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done with a single regular expression?  This will be a burden for others to maintain.  Stripping `(TBC)` or `(TBD)`, then using a regular DateFormatter, will make your code considerably clearer.

Comment: I would strongly discourage you to use such a long and complex regular expression. It's very hard to read and highly error prone and mistakes are easily made. That's why you missed two opening parentheses and asked about it here on Stackoverflow. Using such regular expressions may also impose a performance penalty. It's better to find another way to achieve this, for example, with VGR's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you all I didn't know about the tool. The regex string is actually the result of a concatenation of many different methods that append on the same string. As it is structured I think it's quite nice and modular.

Comment: Your initial regex is wrong, that is why I suggest an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not optimal and even wrong:

- There are alternation operators missing between month names
- There are too many repetitions that only differ in case: use a case insensitive flag
- `[ \(TB(C|D)\)]` is most probably a typo as it is a character class that matches a single char defined inside  it, you need `(?: \(TB[CD]\))?`, an optional non-capturing group.

Use

```
(?i)^29-02-(?:2[048]00|(?:19|2[0-9](?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])-fe[vb]-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(jan|ma[ryi]|ju[li]|au[go]|oct|dec)-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$|^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)-(?:a[pv]r|ju[ni]|sep|nov)-(?:19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}(?: \(TB(C|D)\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LShzz4/2)